# How to perform files integrity check between Amazon-S3 and Google Cloud Storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

I am migrating my data from Amazon-S3 to Google-Cloud Storage.
I have copied my data using **[gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil)**:

```
$ gsutil cp -R s3://my_bucket/* gs://my_bucket
```

What I want to do next is to check if all the files in S3 is properly exist in Google Storage.

At the moment all I did is to do print file list in file and then do simple Unix `diff` but that doesn't really check the file integrity.

What's the good way to check that?

Answer (score 4):

gsutil verifies MD5 checksums on objects copied between cloud providers, so if the recursive copy command completes successfully (shell return code 0), you should have copied everything successfully. Note that gsutil isn't able to compare checksums for S3 objects larger than 5 GiB (which have a non-MD5 checksum that gsutil doesn't support), and will print a warning for cases it encounters.