# what to do with MD5 error when moving data from S3 to gcp

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I understand from [How to perform files integrity check between Amazon-S3 and Google Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45099327/how-to-perform-files-integrity-check-between-amazon-s3-and-google-cloud-storage?answertab=active#tab-top) that files over 5gb will have this issue, but how do I fix it.  I have terabites of files I need to move from S3 to gcp (vendor to my company) every week and am trying to script it.

Comment: Are you seeing an MD5 mismatch, or a report from gsutil that your file contains a non-MD5 checksum that gsutil doesn't support?

Comment: yes, though, weirdly, even though I got the errors, when I checked, all my files actually downloaded anyway.  Maybe its a bug with google where it doesn't have a  legitimate error for Amazon to Google?  either way, my advice to others getting this error, just let it run through and your files will still be copied.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I wasn't clear - I'm asking which of two things you're seeing: Was it (a) an MD5 mismatch, or (b) a report from gsutil that your file contains a non-MD5 checksum that gsutil doesn't support?

Comment: sorry, it was a.

Comment: Please send an email to gs-team@google.com (and reference my name so I see it) with these details: bucket and object name, the date/time when you recently performed an upload and got this MD5 mismatch error, and the value you get when you run the command gsutil hash your-local-filename